# how to find last cell in column that contains specific text

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create an update macro that updates multiple lists. the original data is in its own workbook and then it opens other workbooks and copies the new data into the opened workbooks. I need to be able to find the last cell in column B that contains the letter H.

what I currently have just finds the last cell in the column and looks like this.

```
 Windows("sheet2.xlsm").Activate
Worksheets("sheet1").Activate
Range("B1").End(xlDown).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("sheet 1").Activate
Range("S1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

but as this data has multiple identifiers in it I want to find the last cell that each of the data points occupies. the data is set out H####, A####, B####, C###, T### and so I will need to find last cell for each of the letters that I can copy into the original workbook. In the original workbook I will use a match formula to find the data that hasn't been added and then copy that new data into the workbooks that are getting updated. I am good with the match formula and copying the data into the workbooks but I am having trouble finding a way to find the last cell with specific text in it.

also I realise I should avoid .select and that there are better ways to do this but it is working for me at the minute and I haven't had chance to get my head around dim as long and such yet but if your answer includes something like that then it is fine and i will try and wrap my head around it.

any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can start searching from the last line: for i = lastRow to firstRow step -1. In the loop compare the first Character of the string Left("H#####",1) returns "H". Then do something when you encounter the first of its kind. You can set a flag for each Char you want to find or work with a dictionary. And try to not use Select and Activate if not necessary. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: @lorenzalbert right so I've used an i thing once before, but when it comes to setting flags or working with a dictionary I am completely lost, would you be able to provide an example of how I could implement something like that? also I have heard from multiple people that .select is bad but I don't understand why, would you be able to shed some light on that for me as well please?

Comment: ***Why*** you shouldn't use `Select` etc. - Here is an example. Imagine a program that selects a range of cells, then copies them, then selects a destination and then finally pastes (as your code does right now). Then imagine that during the running of that program, a user or yourself clicks on a cell. That alters the selection. Depending on where the program is at the time, it will either mean only the cell you clicked would be copied, or the cell clicked would become the paste destination. Either way, not ideal.

Comment: @CLR so the reason is because people might get inpatient and then click on the screen while it is running through the code which can cause the paste/copy destination to be the wrong one, okay that makes sense so is the avoiding .select just for copy and paste instances or does it apply to other use cases as well?

Comment: Whenever you use Select/Activate in your code, the selection can easily be altered by a user (or perhaps other process) that would not be predictable. A small-ish problem perhaps, but one that is very easily avoidable - e.g. `Range("B1").End(xlDown).Select : 
Selection.Copy` simply becomes `Range("B1").End(xlDown).Copy`.

Comment: @CLR so it also cuts out unnecessary code and streamlines it. right okay that makes more sense now, thanks, I'm still unsure on dim as long and things like that but I'm sure some more read throughs of the linked post might explain it to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may benefit from SUMPRODUCT and array formulas to get the desired output:

[image]

This formula will return the row number of the last cell **containing** the char `H`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("H",$B$4:$B$14)))*ROW($B$4:$B$14)))
```

Notice that it's an array formula so probably you need to input this with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to make it work, depending on your Excel version

Also, you can use [Evaluate VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate) to get this number inside a code:

```
Sub test()
Dim rng As Range
Dim strFormula As String

Set rng = Range("B4:B14") 'change this to target range
strFormula = "SUMPRODUCT(--MAX((ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""H""," & rng.Address(True, True) & ")))*ROW(" & rng.Address(True, True) & ")))"

Debug.Print Evaluate(strFormula)

End Sub
```

The code will print the value `11` as output but you can store this in a variable and keep coding

By the way, the method **Evaluate** requires english formulation, so all functions **must** be in english and the separator argument is always the comma.

Comment: hi, thankyou for posting this, however I am having trouble with the last bit, I have chosen to use the vba one, but I do not know how to get the output to show up in the sheet. I want to copy the cell and then paste it back into the other sheet so how can I write it so I get b + (the answer form your code) so I can then copy it onto my other sheet would it just be 'B + (strformula)' to give me the cell address?

Comment: wait never mind ill just use the formula version that will be easier for me to work with. thanks for this! it has solved my problem you are a life saver!